# Apps on Ubuntu Software outdated

Tags: 16.04, software-center, libreoffice

I noticed that the version of LibreOffice on Ubuntu Software is still 5.1.6. I also saw comments on the page for Eclipse saying that the version is outdated. Is there a way to get these updated via Ubuntu Software? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? In [17.10 the latest version is 5.4.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libreoffice&searchon=names&suite=artful&section=all), in 16.04 it's 5.1.6... In general software is updated with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: 16.04 is two years old. The deb-package software in 16.04 is also two years old. Ubuntu does not upgrade software (with limited exceptions) after release. If you want newer software, use a newer release of Ubuntu...or install the snap packages instead of the debs.

Comment: Software center is just interface to APT. It follows release freeze rules and so on. If you need newer LibO you can use [their PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) - it has 5.4.4. For stability its recommended to stay on LTS.